# Concatenating to user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

An example would be if I type !greet  it would output "Hello username".

The end goal is to integrate this into a discord bot.

An example of what I have tried:

```
function doGreeting() {
    var input = document.getElementById('userInput')
    alert(input);
}

if (msg.content === prefix + 'greet') {
    msg.channel.sendMessage('Hello ' + doGreeting())
};
```

Comment: If you could add some code it might help others help you out.  Show that you have put in some effort into finding an answer.

Comment: Please review [ask] and put forth some effort into writing some code. If you *have* written some code, please show your [mcve] of what you've tried and ask a targeted question about where exactly you ran into issues. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, and we [expect you to have done some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your input field id or class but I am giving you example below so it may help you.

```
<input type="text" id="my_id" >
<span id="msg"></span>
<script>
var input_val = document.getElementById("my_id");
if(input_val .indexOf("!greet") !=-1){  // if there is !greet word
 var split_str = input_val .split(" ");
 document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Hello "+split_str [1];
}
</script>
```